# Why am I prompted to accept a Microsoft EULA when I run apt-get install?

Tags: apt

Whenever I use `sudo apt-get install packagename`, it will start installing. I will type "Y" when prompted then this will pop up:

[image: screenshot]

```
TrueType core fonts for the Web EULA

END-USER LICENSE AGREEMENT FOR MICROSOFT SOFTWARE

…

                          <Ok>
```

Why does this happen?

Comment: That screen shot is very low resolution and hard to see. It would be helpful to post one with the text visible.

Comment: @muru It looks like they want to know *why* they are prompted with the EULA, not how to accept it.

Comment: @kos no, they're wondering why the y didn't work. Same difference.

Comment: @muru I think the "Y" they're referring to is the "Y" to be typed on the `apt-get` prompt to confirm the installation (I agree, badly worded: they say "it will start installing" and only then they say that, so it sounds like they're typing that during the actual installation, but again I think they're confusing the actual installation with the resolution of the dependencies). But beside they're explicitly asking (twice) why that's happening (once in the title and once at the end).

Comment: You see what I mean? But again, beside, since that's not for sure either, still 3 of the 4 answers below address why that's happening and not how to solve it. Without being sure I think it would be better to leave it open.

Comment: @kos :D I do see that but you don't see what I mean. According to me, OP thinks that y should accept such prompts, so they're wondering why it didn't, which is answered by how one accepts that prompt.

Comment: @muru I do see that, in fact I said it's not really clear, one one hand they're explicitly asking why they're being prompted, on the other they're saying they're pressing Y when prompted, which *sounds* like they're asking for help. But since 3 out of 4 answers address the first one (and OP hasn't been seen since then) better do the most fair thing and uphold this one as a question about why the prompt shows up.

Comment: I'm not saying it's *indeed* a question about that (I'm not in OP's mind), but since both interpretations are reasonable and we'd be stabbing in the dark both ways better do the most fair thing. Mostly everyone understood it that way: if OP wasn't clear they could still follow your link if you're willing to leave it.

Comment: @kos Closing isn't going to delete these answers, you know.

Answer (score 7):

Apt is displaying the license agreement for the package that you are installing. I'm guessing that either you are installing the msttcorefonts package or something that requires the installation of that package like wine, playonlinux, etc. Apt is doing a good thing here, making you aware and agree to the license that the software for this particular package is covered by.

Answer (score 7):

I agree with @Mordoc.

msttcorefonts is a copyright protected package outside of Ubuntu's licensing agreement (logically, as it is from Microsoft)

Most of what is in the apt-cache (can be installed via `apt-get` or Ubuntu Store) has been licensed to allow Ubuntu users to install it by the developers.

However, just because you can install something via `apt-get` doesn't mean it is freely licensed, as djeikyb commented. Some things that can download can be from a non-free repository (where apt downloads the programs from) and thus you can have to agree to an agreement (even though it's in the apt-cache).

Other things, like programs you download from outside (eg...msttcorefonts) may have different licensing agreement.

Answer (score 7):

After being unable to proceed from the EULA, scouring these boards for a solution, getting frustrated; I ended up hitting the "tab" button in a fury, which highlighted the "Ok" button, then prompted me to agree or disagree. After that, terminal resumed its normal function. Cheers!

Comment: I just spent a couple of frustrating hours (OK, with some breaks in between) trying to get mscorefonts installed. TAB! **THANK YOU!!!** :-)

Answer (score 0):

The screenshot is low quality, but I think it's a Microsoft licence of Truefont. It's basicly telling you what you can and can't do with this piece of software. If you want to continue, you'll have to accept the licence(by pressing space)